# Howto cleanly fetch 401 in a Backbone.js based app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

In my Backbone.js based app I am talking to my API that responds with a 401 in case the underlying request was made without or with an invalid authentication token. I'd like to instrument that by navigating to a #login page, every time a 401 is received.

To fetch the 401 I successfully wrapped Backbone.sync, but at that point I get kind of stuck. I tried several strategies here:

1. `throw 'unauthorized'` down in Backbone::sync and try to fetch up in my router. Failed with: 'Uncaught unauthorized'
2. Trying to `#.navigate '#login'` down in Backbone::sync which not only looks odd, but comes with the problem that my app is based on AMD/require.js and I cannot simply access my Backbone.Router instance down in my wrapped `sync` function.

The only solution I see so far would be to create a "globally available" caching object, that gets a reference to my router instance and in turn is put into `define` as a dependency where it is needed. That cache object had to be a singleton and broke my whole 'please-no-globals-and-no-namespaces' - strategy.

I am kind of stuck here. Can anyone point me to a more clean solution to that common problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the redirect in ajaxError:

```
$.ajaxError(function (event, xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 401)
                window.location = '#login';
        });
```

If everything is setup properly you do not need to access the router instance manually. Going to that url should trigger the route function associated with it.

Comment: Undestood. I could do the same window.location = ... in sync where I fetch that response. Good idea. I thought for a clean approach I would have to make use of the router. But that sounds like a good solution. Thank you Anrei

Answer (score 3):

For those using jQuery 1.8 or greater, the syntax has changed:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 401)
            window.location = '#login';
    });
```

See [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) for details.

Comment: In the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/), it's mentioned that it's since 1.9?